# Eclipse :Apache tomcat

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have installed a tomcat plugin in eclipse and made a web project using it. I can run that project by starting server in eclipse but when I close eclipse the server stops and working is terminated. 
Is there is any way to maintain server started while eclipse is not running..... kind of virtual directory in IIS .
Is there a way to correlate apache service and server in eclipse?

Comment: which version of eclipse r u using?

Answer (score 0):

everything you start within eclipse will be terminated when you close eclipse.

you have to deploy your webapp to a standalone server. export your application as war file and put it into your tomcat's webapps folder.

-> http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=123229